# Что озночает initkwargs в данном случае?

Tags: python, django

```
class View(object):

http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']

def __init__(self, **kwargs):

    for key, value in six.iteritems(kwargs):
        setattr(self, key, value)

@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):

    for key in initkwargs:.....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В `as_view` можно передать дополнительные параметры иногда, здесь они просто обрабатываются, как обычные `**kwargs`. Строго говоря, язык тут никак не ограничивает, можно эти параметры назвать хоть `**cheburashkas`, равно как и первый параметр может быть не `cls`, а `krokodil`. Просто программисты договорились называть ссылку на объект в обычных методах `self`, ссылку на класс в методах класса - `cls`, параметры в обычных методах `args` и `kwargs`, а вот в методе класса пусть будут `initkwargs`, чтобы их отличить.

Comment: класс-методы часто являются дополнительными конструкторами, например, `int.from_bytes`. Имя `**initkwargs` может указывать, что именованные параметры будут переданы использованы для инициализации объекта (переданы в `__new__`, `__init__`).